# Show new component on Click on specific element of Component

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I'am learning a reactJS and I created a calendar along a tutorial. Right now I want to improve it and display hours on click I want to show new component (Hours) with hours when I click on small component (Day) that is inside a Bigger component (calendar) Right now it doesn't work properly because I can render new Component when I click on every part of Calendar component not on a day... I am fighting with that for a week and still doesn't find any solution for that, Most important for me is how to pass information that I want to render `<Hours/>` Component when I click on `<Day/>` component which is inside `<Calendar/>` Component.

**Main Component**

```
class Order extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            clicked: false,
            clickedOption: false,
            clickedCalendar: false,
            clickedHours: false,
        };

        this.nameClick = this.nameClick.bind(this);

    }



    showCategory() {
        this.setState({
            clickedOption: !this.state.clickedOption
        })
    }

    nameClick() {

        this.setState({
            clicked: !this.state.clicked
        })
    }

    showHours() {
        this.setState({
            clickedHours: !this.state.clickedHours
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TimeCalendar/>
                <Employee onClick={() => this.showCategory()}/>
                {this.state.clickedOption && <Categories onClick={() => this.nameClick()}/>}
                {this.state.clicked && <Calendar onClick={() => this.showHours()}/>}
                {this.state.clickedHours && <Hours/>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Calendar Component**

```
class Calendar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            disabled: false,
            month: moment(),
            selected: moment().startOf('day')
        };

        this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);

        this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    }

    previous() {
        const {
            month,
        } = this.state;

        this.setState({
            month: month.subtract(1, 'month')
        });

    }

    next() {
        const {
            month,
        } = this.state;

        this.setState({
            month: month.add(1, 'month'),
        })
    }

    select(day) {
        this.setState({
            selected: day.date,
            month: day.date.clone(),
        });
    }

    renderWeeks() {
        let weeks = [];
        let done = false;
        let date = this.state.month.clone().startOf('month').add("w" - 1).day('Sunday');
        let count = 0;
        let monthIndex = date.month();

        const {
            selected,
            month,
        } = this.state;

        while (!done) {
            weeks.push(
                <Week
                    key={date}
                    date={date.clone()}
                    month={month}
                    select={(day) => this.select(day)}
                    selected={selected}
                />
            );
            date.add(1, 'w');

            done = count++ > 2 && monthIndex !== date.month();
            monthIndex = date.month();
        }
        return weeks;
    }

    renderMonthLabel() {
        const {
            month
        } = this.state;
        return <span className="month-label">{month.format("MMMM YYYY")}</span>;
    }

    previousMonth() {
        let lastMonth = this.state.month.subtract('month', 1).calendar();

        if (lastMonth === true) {
            this.state.disabled = true
        } else {
            this.state.disabled = false
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-xs-4">
                <section className="calendar" {...this.props}>
                    <header className="header">
                        <div className="month-display row">
                            <i className="arrow fa fa-angle-left" /*disabled={this.previousMonth()}*/
                               onClick={this.previous}/>
                            {this.renderMonthLabel()}
                            <i className="arrow fa fa-angle-right" onClick={this.next}/>
                        </div>
                        <DayNames/>
                    </header>
                    {this.renderWeeks()}
                </section>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Week and Day Component**

```
class Week extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showHours: false
        }

    }

    showHours() {
        this.setState({
            showHours: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        let days = [];
        let {
            date,
        } = this.props;

        const {
            month,
            selected,
            select,
        } = this.props;

        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            let day = {
                name: date.format('dd').substring(0, 1),
                number: date.date(),
                isCurrentMonth: date.month() === month.month(),
                isToday: date.isSame(new Date(), 'day'),
                date: date
            };
            days.push(
                <Day
                    day={day}
                    selected={selected}
                    select={select}
                    key={day.num}
                />
            )
            ;
            date = date.clone();
            date.add(1, 'day');
        }
        return (
            <div className="row week" key={days[0]}>
                {days}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Day extends Component {
    render() {
        const {
            day,
            day: {
                date,
                isCurrentMonth,
                isToday,
                number
            },
            select,
            selected
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <span
                key={date.toString()}
                className={"day" + (isToday ? " today" : "") + (isCurrentMonth ? "" : " different-month") + (date.isSame(selected) ? " selected" : "")}
                onClick={() => {select(day)}}>
                {number}
                </span>
        )
    }
}
```

**Hour Component**

```
class Hours extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }


    render() {
        const marginStyle = {
            marginTop: "10px"
        };


        return (
            <div {...this.props} className="block-hours col-xs-4">
                <form action="">
                <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    8:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    8:30
                   <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    9:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    9:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                    </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    10:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                    </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    10:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    11:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    11:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    12:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    12:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    13:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    13:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    14:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    14:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    15:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    15:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    16:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    16:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    17:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    17:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    18:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    18:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    19:00
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <span className="block-hours hour-element">
                    19:30
                    <input type="radio" name="hours"/>
                </span>
                    <br/>
                    <div style={marginStyle}></div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-custom-color">Zapisz się na wizytę</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call onClick when calendar is clicked, but you should to pass this func as prop:

```
{this.state.clicked && <Calendar showHours={this.showHours}/>}
```

And in caledar just call this function when day is clicked:

```
select(day) {
    this.setState({
        selected: day.date,
        month: day.date.clone(),
    });
    this.props.showHours();
}
```

Comment: But When I add this prop I got an error "this.props.showHours is not a function"

Comment: Have you changed onClick to showHours in {this.state.clicked && <Calendar showHours={this.showHours}/>}?

Comment: I didn't notice that but Right now When I change it I got an error message "cannot read property "clickedHours" of undefined

Comment: This problem has dissapear but Right now When I click On Day it doesn't render Hours component and there isn't any error message

Comment: Glad to help :)